# Selenium Python: Selecting all items in a class and putting them into a list?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, classname

Is there any way to get all the elements with a certain class and put into a list? for example:

```
<li class="Fruit">Apple</li>
<li class="Fruit">Orange</li>
```

I would like to put *Apple* and *Orange* in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract and print the texts e.g. *Apple*, *Orange*, etc from all of the `<li class="Fruit">` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name` and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Fruit")])
  ```
- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Fruit")])
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='Fruit']")])
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME` and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "Fruit")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Fruit")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='Fruit']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 1):

```
  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Fruit")
```

Find elements returns all elements that much the given criteria ,here the class name , it returns list

you can print the text as:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Fruit")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

or

```
elemsText = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Fruit")]
print(elemsText]
```

Comment: if I assign this to a variable and print it it says [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4ae51c4789941334d27581669517b12a", element="d53193f3-6f47-4911-abbe-f4618062ee21")>            I would like for it to print the items inside the element. If there is any way to do that?

Comment: @TheBotlyNoob its an array of webelement what you want to print in that ?

Comment: Added the forloop to iterate over it and print text